# difficulties with ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

I followed [this](https://www.developphp.com/video/JavaScript/Custom-Confirm-Box-Programming-Tutorial) lesson (video/code) to make confirmation box and I wanted to add an AJAX request for deleting data from my database. However I just can't get it to work. Here is my AJAX code that I added to the `deletePost` function:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "delete.php",
    data: db_id,
    success: function(){}
});
```

and here is my `delete.php` (`$conn` is connection to DB):

```
<?php
    global $conn;
    if (isset($_POST['id']))    
    {
        $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['id']);
        $delete_product = "DELETE FROM products WHERE id = '$id'";
        $run_delete_product = mysqli_query($conn, $delete_product); 
    }
?>
```

The database is in my phpmyadmin with a table called `products` which has `id` and `product_name` columns.

Comment: What is the value of `db_id`?

Comment: have you tried printing the output of $_POST['id'] ? does it really print what you expect?

Comment: db_id  is the id from table products, it is going to be 1 or 2 or 3 and so on

Comment: In that case see @Ayyanar G's answer.

Comment: @Enjoyted - i tried to echo that ($_POST['id']) it doesn't show anything  o.o

Comment: Yes this is normal. This is why you shoud always try debugging your code when it is not working. You are expecting $_POST['id'] but it doesn't exist as you are not sending it. So you never enter your if, and therefore never delete any data.

Comment: @Enjoyted - but axaj should send the data to the php function (delete.php) but it appears that it is not sending anything....

Comment: try printing $_POST alone to see if there is anything else inside it. However if you do exactly as @Ayyanar G says you should be doing fine

Comment: found the problem...man i feel silly, because delete.php is a separate file it needs to INCLUDE the connection!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this, `data` attribute contains the data to be sent to the server, you have to pass it as `key/value` pairs

```
$.ajax({
   type:"POST",
   url:"delete.php",
   data:{id:db_id},
   success:function(){}
});
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? Please add an explanation of what you did and why you did it that way not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: The lack of explanation is the only thing stopping this from being a good answer instead of a game of spot-the-difference

Comment: not working :( i added the key/value like you did but my delete.php is not receiving the data

Comment: thank you @Ayyanar G, the ajax code works great. the problem was with the delete.php, it needed to include the connection because delete.php is a separate file...man i feel silly :P

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$.ajax({
   type:"POST",
   url:"delete.php",
   data:'id='+db_id,
   success:function(){
      console.log("success");
   }
});
```